# Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object, Codeigniter OAuth2

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use [philsturgeon's OATH2 spark for CodeIgniter](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2) to authenticate a user using Facebook. I installed the Spark and tried the Usage Example tha he gives in the github.

In the following code I only changed the id and secret.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
    public function session($provider)
    {
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');

        $this->load->spark('oauth2-0.4.0');

        $provider = $this->oauth2->provider($provider, array(
            'id' => 'My_ID',
            'secret' => 'MY_Secret',
        ));

        if ( ! $this->input->get('code'))
        {
            // By sending no options it'll come back here
            $provider->authorize();
        }
        else
        {
            // Howzit?
            try
            {
                $token = $provider->access($_GET['code']);

                $user = $provider->get_user_info($token);

                // Here you should use this information to A) look for a user B) help a new user sign up with existing data.
                // If you store it all in a cookie and redirect to a registration page this is crazy-simple.
                echo "<pre>Tokens: ";
                var_dump($token);

                echo "\n\nUser Info: ";
                var_dump($user);
            }

            catch (OAuth2_Exception $e)
            {
                show_error('That didnt work: '.$e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to call the controller using

```
http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/auth/session/facebook
```

I get the following:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Auth::$session

Filename: libraries/Provider.php

Line Number: 117


Fatal error: Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object in
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\tddd27\sparks\oauth2-0.4.0\libraries\Provider.php on line 117

Is something wrong in the library or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like the session library has not been loaded. Try adding this near the top of your function

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

You could also have the library autoload by adding it to your `application/config/autoload.php` file

Comment: You are true. That was the problem